# How to check whether an IC has gone bad or not?

Tags: integrated-circuit, logic-gates, breadboard

## My Question

I have unfortunately, had an incident with my the 74LS08 (And Gate) IC. When I accidentally powered it incorrectly, the IC started to heat, very quickly. I was powering it using an adapter from a wall socket (5V of input power).
I cannot remember exactly the wire up, however the IC was getting hot very quickly. I unplugged it from the mains and from the connection onto the breadboard. There seems to be no visible damage to the IC, however the area of the breadboard below it seems to have widened a bit (I was bridging it over the middle channel of the breadboard). There was also no smoke, or anything else apart from the IC heating and the breadboard damage.

---

## My Question

So what is the best way to test whether the it is usable? I currently don't have a spare, so I don't really want to be throwing it away unless I can be sure that it is definitely dead.

---

## Other Notes

I have checked out both other questions on whether an IC is fried, however I have seen no smoke or the like to make it obvious that it is definitely useless.

---

## Datasheet

https://www.bitsbox.co.uk/data/7400/74HC08.pdf

Comment: Hook it up correctly, being prepared to pull power if it heats again, and see if it works.  Realize you can't really trust it now, but you're not using a DIP packaged 74LS08 on a breadboard for anything very important anyway, so the main concern would be if it started getting hot again.  They're not expensive, get a new one next time you get components.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Thanks. Sorry to be a pain, but could you send me a quick link to a simple circuit to test this. I have tried my original circuit, however nothing has happened. However, that is a big circuit and their may be faults elsewhere.

Comment: I think I will just use to definitely high inputs to the gate and then check whether that lights the LED.

Comment: requests for examples are explicitly off topic on stack exchange sites

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Sorry, I have not seen that. Should I delete that comment? Thanks :D

Comment: The datasheetshould have a test or typical application circuit

Comment: I usually to check to see if pins are shorted that should not be.

Comment: If you keep using it, mark it in some way (with a white marker, or a sticker, or carve an X in the plastic, ...). That way you have a reminder the chip might be faulty if the circuit it's in misbehaves.

Comment: Does it give the correct logic level outputs for all inputs? If not, no point in testing it further.

Comment: If you decide it is bad, smash it up into little bits and discard it. There is nothing more frustrating than debugging a circuit which doesn't work because somebody mixed bad parts in with good parts.

Comment: @mkeith, I have tested it out and have had some weird results which I am looking into.

Comment: @marcelm, Great minds think alike - already done that!!! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an AND gate. Give it two inputs from somewhere like buttons and observe output with something like LED or oscilloscope or multimeter.

Answer (score 0):

One quick-and-dirty test for some kinds of blown TTL ICs is to simply try powering them from a suitably current-limited power supply.  If you've "let the smoke out", the blown ICs often appear as open circuits or shorts to the supply voltage.